# window.requestAnimationFrame silently fails to invoke callback, but generates a valid requestID, when invoked inside of a cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I am developing inside of a Google Chrome Extension. In this environment, I have the ability to inject JavaScript into third-party websites after requesting the appropriate permissions. As such, I am injecting code into an iframe referencing a cross-domain resource, but am not bound by the same cross-origin security policies as would be expected in a 'normal' environment.

The code I am executing inside of this iframe is:

```
var requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    console.log("Success");
});
console.log("Request Id:", requestId);
```

After this code is executed, my output looks like:

> Request Id: 1

The callback of requestAnimationFrame is never executed. requestAnimationFrame is defined. The callback works fine if I use a non-optimized call such as setInterval.

The callback **is executed properly outside of the iframe** but no security errors are shown in my console when it fails inside of the iframe. This is only for the latest version of Google Chrome -- do not worry about other implementations of requestAnimationFrame.

Are there any steps I can take to debug this issue? window.requestAnimationFrame trails off into native code and my requestId is valid... so I'm at a bit of a loss.

**EDIT:**

Here is the full source code for reproducing the issue as a small Google Chrome extension: https://gist.github.com/MeoMix/37b4dbdbb3bd48f3c9e2

Here is a downloadable zip of the source above: https://mega.co.nz/#!2BFA1agY!JSZC1BFBza3rU4LnqlZqcR9neZQRJn0yh1U6tu2GWo4

Comment: Can you provide valid code and a page to reproduce the issue? Did the page override RAF? E.g. `window.requestAnimationFrame=function(){return 1;};`?

Comment: I console.log'ed window.requestAnimationFrame and the console indicated that the body of the function was native code. I'm under the assumption that means it wasn't stubbed. I will craft a working example this evening and update my post -- sorry for the lack of solid information. If it's any help -- I am injecting the code into the iframe generated by YouTube's API.

Comment: It's unlikely, but not impossible. And "[native code]" doesn't tell you much; `window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){return 1;}).bind(null);` would show the same behavior, and also "[native code]".

Comment: Interesting, TIL. What does native code actually indicate? I thought it was going off to my GPU or something to figure out when it could render again.

Comment: By "native code doesn't tell you much", I meant that anyone could create a function that serializes as "function() { [native code] }`. If you see "[native code]", just read it as "serialization of function's source not possible".

Comment: @RobW I have finished creating a demoable example. Please see my edit. It contains the full source of my example as well as a .zip file which is runnable as a Chrome Extension. The requestAnimationFrame callback never returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with iframes, but with the invisibility of background pages.

Think of a background page as a non-focused tab. If you use `requestAnimationFrame` in a non-active tab, then the callback will not be called until the tab is focused again, as shown in the next example. Since background pages are never be "focused", RAF callbacks will never be invoked.

Paste the following code in a console, and move to a different tab. Wait a few seconds before activating the tab again. You will see that the logged timestamps in the console are very close. This shows that the callback of RAF will only be called when the tab is focused again.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.time(1);
    console.time(2)
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        console.timeEnd(1)
    });
}, 2000)
window.onfocus = function() {
    console.timeEnd(2);
};
```

The "solution" to your problem is to use the good old `setTimeout` instead:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('Success');
}, 25); // 40 Hz.
```

Comment: Intriguing. I had no idea. Yep, I can definitely use a setTimeout. I just thought that it was easy performance gains by using requestAnimationFrame. Thanks for investigating!!

Comment: You've just saved my life!!! I was trying to use tracking.js in a background script on an extension and I was getting no errors but it was not working either! Now I can change tracking.js code and finish my project. Thanks!