# jQuery selector not working on iframe contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This part of a script works fine on a normal page:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".counter").countimator();
});
</script>
```

But when that same page is loaded in an iframe on a page on another domain, it doesn't work.

Is there a way to get this selector/code work when the page is loaded within an iframe? I want to give people a iframe code that they can use on their personal websites to get the content of my page on their website.

### Edit

I published the basic code on http://joomlaground.com/iframe_test/

The http://joomlaground.com/iframe_test/clock.php runs standalone like it should.

Then I created a very basic iframe page iframe.php which iframe the clock.php. However then the clock.php is not counting any more.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tested, whether the `$(function() {...}` is actually fired within your iframe by putting something like an `alert('iframe alert');` into it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, the alert box is working. I think he cannot find the selector.

Comment: hmmm... and the element you are looking for with `$('.counter')`  and the definition of the jQuery-method `countimator()` are both accessible from within the same iframe?

Comment: Yep, I think so. Maybe you can find a solution in my code http://joomlaground.com/iframe_test/

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem. However, it seems the `countimator()` method itself has a problem in the iframe context: The `$('.counter')` element was clearly found again in the iframe context and showed up with the same contents as before, but `countimator()` seems unable to do anything with it.

Comment: Well, it *does* do *something* with it, but it stops somewhere *midway*! You will have to look closer into `countimator` I am afraid ...

Answer (score 0):

When you move this script in an iframe then it means you are running your script in a new window.

Now in new window you are trying to access some library function:

```
$(".counter").countimator();
```

That can only be done if you have that library included in the source of that iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responce! Do you mean that I have to put all the java-script call's in the page with the iframe code? That is no problem but I have copied al these <script src="...."></script> lines and even the css links <link href="..." rel="stylesheet"> lines to that page but still it doesn't work.

Comment: So, what do you mean exactly with "include library in the source of the iframe"?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, by include library in the source of iframe I meant that include the script like jquery, the library you are using and the above code in the html of the iframe. For e.g.  in case of <iframe src="index.html"/>, index.html should have all the scripts.

Comment: Yes that file has all the sources already in it. So when I run index.html standalone everything works fine. But when I run the iframe.html with calls the index.html in a iframe than it is not working. I think you are on the right track by saying that it has to do with running in a new window, but I don't understand why it doesn't find the selector than  anymore? Maybe I have to point him somehow to look in the iframe???

Comment: This way I am not able to figure out the problem this way, can you please share some basic code for me?

Comment: Thanks, that you want to look in the code. I have published it on http://joomlaground.com/iframe_test/. Any idea how to get clock.php working in a iframe?

Comment: I have to go in a meeting now. I will check once back.

Comment: I have tried working on it.  Issue is replicable. This issue also comes outside iframe i.e. in normal window but occasionally. It seems to be an issue with countimator library. I am investigating it further. Will share my findings.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. It is a cross domain issue.

Comment: I have tested his code on my own php space (only *one* domain) and it showed up with the same problem. So, at least on my php-space, the problem cannot be cross-domain related. hmmm ...

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely not a cross-domain issue and it does not appear outside the iframe. I think somewhere inside the countimator script it get lost when the page with the script is not the main parent page of the browser. I am spending already a few days of frustration on this issue, but cannot find it.

Comment: Yes you are right. It seems to be an issue with library or can say conflicting libraries. I performed a simple test in which i remove the template library and its corresponding html. I also removed the countimator css. Which means i had only 3 js - jquery, countimator, countimator wheel and our function ofcourse. In html i had only 1 element i.e. counter. With above setup it was working perfectly in and outside iframe. I performed the test in chrome and firefox and tested atleast 10 times. Which makes me conclude it is a problem with libraries conflict. Lets further drill this down.

Comment: I am still desperate searching for a fix. Can it have to do something with the focused window, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791219/window-requestanimationframe-silently-fails-to-invoke-callback-but-generates-a

Comment: I don't think so. Did you tried what I have suggested above? Did that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If '.counter' element is outside of the iframe you're running the internal iframe script has no access to this element as the current document and iframe are separate documents. If you'll have any questions don't hesitate to ask below.

Comment: No, everything is inside the iframe. The iframe is only used to show it on different websites.